# Python, введение числа из заданного диапазона

Tags: python

Как сделать так что бы пользователь ввел переменную из заданного диапазона от 1 до 8. А если она не из заданного диапазона ошибка выдавалась и пользователь должен ввести переменную заново, и так, до тех пор пока переменная не будет удовлетворять данному диапазону.

Comment: Цикл -> пользователь вводит -> ввёл верно -> завершаем цикл.

Answer (score 5):

В переменной `a` лежит строка из требуемых символов, проверяем пока не введут правильный

```
a = "12345678"
n = input("Нужно число от 1 до 8: ")
while n not in a:
    print("Нет, Вы ошиблись")
    n = input("Нужно число от 1 до 8: ")
print("Наконец то: ", n)
```

Comment: `while True: n=input();if n in a: break;`

Answer (score 3):

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('> ')) 
        if n >= 1 and n <= 8:
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter n ∈ [1;8]!')
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter number')
print(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто прикольно:

```
pip3 install getch
```

```
from getch import getch
while True:
    try:
        n = int(getch())
    except:
        pass
    if n >= 1 and n <= 8:
        print(n)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

как вариант можно приводить все значения меньше диапазона к минимульному допустимому значению, а все значения больше, к максимальному допустимому
a = max(min(int(input("введи число от 1 до 8: ) " )),8),1)
print(a)